# XSLT: open document error

Tags: xml, xslt, altova

I've got a file called Dictionary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DICTIONARY SNAPSHOT_DATE="30.07.2014 17:55:37" SNAPSHOT_CREATOR="XYZ" MODULE="Core" MODULE_VERSION_FROM="ALL" MODULE_VERSION_UNTIL="1.04">
  <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="58384" VARIANT_ID="13692" STATUS="NEW">
    <LANG_ENTRY LANG_ID="EN" STATUS="PROOFED"><![CDATA[Reset target]]></LANG_ENTRY>
  </DICT_ENTRY>
... snip...
</DICTIONARY>
```

and I try to use it in my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="dictionary_file">Dictionary.xml</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="dictstrings" select="document($dictionary_file)"/>
... snip...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generates an error (in Altova XMLSpy Professional Edition v2012 sp1) saying

```
XTDE1170: Error in XPath 2.0 expression
Error retrieving resource 'Dictionary.xml'
```

BUT, if I simplify the content of Dictionary.xml, so that it reads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DICTIONARY>
    <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="58384">
        <LANG_ENTRY>Reset target</LANG_ENTRY>
    </DICT_ENTRY>
... snip ...
</DICTIONARY>
```

Then it loads and uses the content of Dictionary.xml.

I assume there is something about the format of the original Dictionary.xml that it doesn't like. Do you know what? Or is there some other problem that I haven't identified here?

Edit: or to be more precise, do you have a good suggestion as to how I can make some XSLT so that my users can run an XSLT stylesheet, using an unaltered dictionary file in the original format?
(Thanks for the other edits.)

Comment: Okay, it is the `<![CDATA[Reset target]]>` that it doesn't like. If I strip it down to just `Reset target`, then it is fine.

Comment: Still, if you have a solution that allows me to use the original file, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: The CDATA section looks fine to me, if you can load the file into a web browser like IE or Mozilla and they don't show parse errors then try an Altova support forum, asking them if their XML parser in the version of Altova XML Spy you use is known to have any problems with CDATA section. I can't imagine it would have any but as a customer of that product that should be able to tell you.

Comment: XMLSpy does not have a problem with the original CDATA file, if I run XSLT on it directly: but only if I open it with the document() function. Web browsers also open the CDATA file fine.

Comment: I've posted it to an Altova forum too. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I my view it does not make a difference whether an XML file has a CDATA section or not, the document function simply uses an XML parser to parse the document. If AltovaXML Spy is different I would ask in an Altova support forum http://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen. It's on [that forum](http://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1100000469). We'll see what they say.